Inference for a data-adaptive parameter
You have data on a continuous variable $A$, representing the dosage of a drug, and a continuous outcome $Y$, representing some health outcome.
I want to estimate the "optimal" dosage of $A$, that which minimises $Y$. Lets call it $A_{opt}$.
Estimating $A_{opt}$ is straightforward. It is the value $a$ which minimises $E[Y|A=a]$, which could be estimated by linear regression (for example).
I then want to estimate the "value" of $Y$ under $A_{opt}$. I can get this from the fitted regression, by passing in $A_{opt}$. But the problem is that i) I am then treating $A_{opt}$ as known, even though it was estimated (invalidating variance estimates) and ii) the same data was used to identify $A_{opt}$ as to estimate the Value for that dosage.
Bootstrapping solves the first problem but not the second. Two-fold sample splitting probably works but seems wasteful. K-fold CV would result in several values of $A_{opt}$, which complicates presentation. What kind of options do we have for this problem? I would appreciate any references!
IN BRIEF
How can I:

Estimate a data-adaptive parameter (i.e., the "optimal" dose of a drug, w/r/t an outcome)
Get a valid estimate and valid uncertainty for the value of the outcome under that optimal dose

